# Displaying Error: Too many re-renders in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

This is the code that I have written to change the background video based on the user input. The background has a video based on the weather of the location the user enters.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import cloudy from "../assets/cloudy.mp4";
import sunny from "../assets/sunny.mp4";
import rainy from "../assets/rainy.mp4";
import winter from "../assets/winter.mp4";

const weathers = [cloudy, sunny, rainy, winter];

const Background = (props) => {
const [weather, setWeather] = useState(weathers[1]);

const temp = props.info.current.temp_c;
const rain = props.info.current.precip_mm;

if (rain > 2.5) setWeather(weathers[2]);
else if (temp < 8) setWeather(weathers[3]);

return (
  <Fragment>
    <video autoPlay loop muted className="back-video">
      <source src={weather} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Here's how I return in the App component :

```
return (
<Fragment>
  <div className="container">
    <h1>Weather App</h1>
    <Input newLocation={locationHandler} />
    <article>{content}</article>
  </div>
  <article>{background}</article>
</Fragment>
)
```

I tried using UseEffect since I have a re-rendering error but in that case it doesn't change the background at all

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (rain > 2.5) setWeather(weathers[2]);
 else if (temp < 8) setWeather(weathers[3]);
}, [weather, temp, rain])
```

or only weather as a dependency.

Edit: My App component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, Fragment } from 
"react";
import Background from "./components/Background";
import Weather from "./components/Weather";
import Input from "./UI/Input";

function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [location, newLocation] = useState("New Delhi");

  const locationHandler = (place) => {
    newLocation(place);
  };

  const fetchweatherHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
  try {
  //console.log(location);
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json? 
 key={apiKey}&q=${location}&aqi=yes`
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  //console.log(data);
  setWeather(data);
    } catch (error) {
  setError(error.message);
    }
setIsLoading(false);
  }, [location]);

  useEffect(() => {
fetchweatherHandler();
  }, [fetchweatherHandler]);

  let content = <p>Found no weather.</p>;
  let background = <p>No Background</p>;

  if (weather && Object.keys(weather).length > 0) {
    content = weather && <Weather info={weather} />;
    background = weather && <Background info={weather} />;
  }

  if (error) {
    content = <p>{error}</p>;
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    content = <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
<Fragment>
  <div className="container">
    <h1>Weather App</h1>
    <Input newLoc={locationHandler} />
    <article>{content}</article>
  </div>
  <article>{background}</article>
</Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

So `UseEffect` works like this. Which ever state you are passing in the `[]`, useEffect will listen to its state and whenever the state changes it executes the code inside the useEffect. It also runs the code once the component mounts.

In your case, you are passing `[weather]` and inside the `useEffect` you are changing the `setWeather` which changes `weather`. So `useEffect` runs again which set's `weather` again and it goes on causing an infinite loop and causing too many rerender error.

You can use it like the below but it won't rerender every time weather changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (rain > 2.5) setWeather(weathers[2]);
 else if (temp < 8) setWeather(weathers[3]);
}, [temp, rain])
```

checkout the topic `lifecycle of components in react functional components` to know more about this

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understood it very well. But even after putting [temp,rain] as dependencies, the background doesn't change.

Comment: Can you tell me about your requirement?. Does the rain and temp changes dynamically and if it does, is it also using useState?.

Comment: Rain and temp change when the props passed to it change. This happens when user types a new location which is handled in the Input component. Based on this new location and its values ( props.info.current.temp_c ), I wish to change the background.

Comment: Are you using any API to get the data when user inputs the location? Please share the code for the component where your are passing the props to the background component

Comment: Yes, I am using an API to fetch user location. I'll update the question with my App component

Comment: I would suggest passing the weather state from App.js to Background component and use it in the useEffect(). [weather,temp, rain]. You have to change the name of the state in background component, as both components use same name in app and background component or pass the state with a different name. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Did so but still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue here, please make a codesandbox for your code. I will take a  look